# issue with Kitewire apt repository when running apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

My issue is as the title states. this is the error message that I'm getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu uma Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

the problem is that when I do `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` I cannot find the Kitewire repository. Why is this happening?

Comment: if it's possible, I'd like to remove the kitewire repository

Comment: It might be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Or use `grep` to find the entry. It should be there.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your error message implies you're using Linux Mint and not Ubuntu*